# Count cell per month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I look for a code for the number of times a value is in a cell, on a monthly basis

So

```
1-1-19   KS
2-1-19
3-1-19   KS
.
.
1-2-19   KS
2-2-19
3-2-19

January  2
February 1
```

is this possible?

Comment: I don t understand your question. Can you detail your question (maybe with an example).

Answer (score 0):

- Assume that your dates are in column `A`, your `KS` is in column `B`.
- In cell `D1:D12`  you have the first of each month entered and given a *custom number format* of `mmmm` so it just shows `January`, `February`, etc.
- The formula `=MATCH($D1,$A:$A,0)` will give the row number that the month starts on.
  For simplicity I'll call this **`Start_Row`**.
- The formula `=MATCH(EOMONTH($D1,0),$A:$A,0)` will give the row number that the month ends on.
  I'll call this **`End_Row`**.
- The formula `INDEX($B:$B,`**`Start_Row`**`):INDEX($B:$B,`**`End_Row`**`)` will set a reference in column `B` to all rows between the first of the month and the end of the month.
  I'll call this **`CountRange`**.
- Now you just need to count what's in that reference using either:
  `=COUNTIF(`**`CountRange`**`,"KS")` to count just *KS*
  `=COUNTA(`**`CountRange`**`)` to count any non-blank cells.

So the full formula, without any helper columns, would be:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($D1,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(EOMONTH($D1,0),$A:$A,0)),"KS")
```

Keeping in mind that `D1` contains `01/01/2019`

Comment: Or you could use `=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT($A:$A,"mmmmyy")=TEXT($D1,"mmmmyy"))*($B:$B<>""))` but that's a bit slow.